# Transform row value using like dimensions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I current have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Account Date    Region  Type    Measure Value
Bob     31-Jan  East    A       Sales   7
Bob     31-Jan  West    A       Sales   8
Bob     31-Jan  East    B       Expense 5
Bob     31-Jan  West    B       Expense 10
```

The only difference is my actual dataframe has several different fields for the "account", "date", and "type" dimensions.

My goal here is to change the value of *only* Bob's accounts to be a 50/50 split between the regions

for example it would look like:

```
 Account    Date    Region  Type    Measure Value
 Bob        31-Jan  East    A       Sales   7.5
 Bob        31-Jan  West    A       Sales   7.5
 Bob        31-Jan  East    B       Expense 5
 Bob        31-Jan  West    B       Expense 10
```

I've tried filtering my df on Bob and sales to start:

```
 df = df[df['Account'] == 'Bob']
 df = df[df['Measure'] == 'Sales']
```

Next I make all of the Regions the same:

```
 df['Region'] = 'East and West'
```

Once here, I've tried several groupby functions, but I can't get to seem any of them to return the correct values.

Should I try to transpose my df and work from there?

Comment: Can you explain why Type B value not become 7.5 and 7.5

Comment: I am only trying to apply the transformation to the "Sales" measure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need to do this for the `'sales'` values for a single person, then use boolean indexing and `mean`

```
mask = (df.Measure == 'Sales') & (df.Account == 'Bob')
df.loc[mask, 'Value'] = df.loc[mask, 'Value'].mean()
```

However, if you wanted to do this for the `'sales'` measures for **every** account, you should use `groupby` + `transform`.

```
mask = (df.Measure == 'Sales')
df.loc[mask, 'Value'] = df[mask].groupby('Account').Value.transform('mean')
```

Output:

```
  Account    Date Region Type  Measure  Value
0     Bob  31-Jan   East    A    Sales    7.5
1     Bob  31-Jan   West    A    Sales    7.5
2     Bob  31-Jan   East    B  Expense    5.0
3     Bob  31-Jan   West    B  Expense   10.0
```

In the last case, you could add more columns to the grouping columns, for instance if you wanted to calculate the average sales for each account on each date, of each type.

Comment: love this solution! the only issue i have is that it's taking the average of all of my dates, where i want it to only average when dates are equal... do you know how to incorporate this?

Comment: Yes, change the grouping columns, so that it's `df[mask].groupby(['Account', 'Date']).Value.transform('mean')`

Comment: thanks so much. I have one more question if it's not too difficult. Say for example that I wanted a 40/60 split instead of 50/50. would that add a lot of complexity to the code?

Comment: @Ben No, it wouldn't complicate things terribly; there are various ways to do it. Would it be a split based on `Region`? And in that case, do you only ever have two regions that are represented once within each group (account-date pair)?

Comment: great question - yes it would be a split based on regions and there could theoretically be more than two in my dataset

Comment: @Ben in that case, I think it may be best for another question. You'd need to provide some more sample data, that way we can see how the averaging should occur (i.e. do you want to average by region first, then apply the weights, or do you want to assign equal weighting to each row, and still weight the regions accordingly).

Comment: apologies - i don't know the best way to supply you with some additional sample data. I think your question is fair straightforward to answer, though: for each date of the one particular account, I want the weights to be multiplied by the total between all the regions of that date. So for the sample data above, a 40/60 east/west split would show a value of 6 for east and 9 for west. let me know if that makes sense